# Sorting List of values in a RDD in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a RDD in which my key is an id and values include list of ids. I want to sort the list of values in ascending order
For Example

```
1, list(12,3,8,10)
2, list(42,3,65,33)
3, list(6,2,4,1)
```

Output

```
1, list(3,8,10,12)
2, list(3,33,42,65)
3, list(1,2,4,6)
```

**RDD Creation**
So I have created RDD after joining two different RDDs and then used it `productIterator` to create `list of values` which is giving me RDD of type `RDD(Int, List[Any])`

I tried 
`rdd.mapValues(x=> _.2.sorted)` different sort methods but no luck

Answer (score 2):

You're nearly there.

`mapValues`, as it's name suggests, applies your mapping function only to the values. Your code looks like you're trying to extract the second element from a key/value tuple, which would, I imagine be throwing errors.

You can either use `map` or `mapValues`. `map` needs to return a tuple if you wish to retain your key, so `mapValues` is simpler, but I'll show you both ways. So we're starting with an `RDD[(Int, List[Int])]` which I've already constructed, and using `collect()` to view it.

```
scala> start
res17: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, List[Int])] = MapPartitionsRDD[6] at map at <console>:37

scala> start.collect()
res18: Array[(Int, List[Int])] = Array((1,List(12, 3, 8, 10)), (2,List(42, 3, 65, 33)))
```

Firstly, let's do the simplest thing:

```
scala> start.mapValues(x => x.sorted).collect()
res19: Array[(Int, List[Int])] = Array((1,List(3, 8, 10, 12)), (2,List(3, 33, 42, 65)))
```

As you can see, it returns the ordering you expect.

Using map to modify the key/value tuple is pretty simple, so long as you preserve your key. I recommend using Scala's case function syntax to destructure the tuple into named arguments, instead of having to refer to `tuple._1`/`tuple._2`

```
scala> start.map({ case (k, v) => (k, v.sorted) }).collect()
res21: Array[(Int, List[Int])] = Array((1,List(3, 8, 10, 12)), (2,List(3, 33, 42, 65)))
```

But using the tuple syntax you're familiar with:

```
scala> start.map(x => (x._1, x._2.sorted)).collect()
res22: Array[(Int, List[Int])] = Array((1,List(3, 8, 10, 12)), (2,List(3, 33, 42, 65)))
```

I hope this helps. *Edit* as it looks like your issue is due to a lack of type information, I've added how I created my RDD that I used to run through scenarios.

```
val input: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(1, 12, 3, 8, 10), Array(2, 42, 3, 65, 33))

val start: RDD[(Int, List(Int)] = sc.parallelize(input).map({ 
  case Array(key, value @ _*) => (key, value.toList)
})
```

If you look at the method signature for [List.sorted](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#sorted[B>:A](implicitord:scala.math.Ordering[B]):Repr) you'll see it has an implicit parameter which tells Scala how to sort the list.

Scala provides default implementations for things like numbers and strings, but it locates the implicit implementation based on the type of your List. It has no default for a list of `Any`, which is the equivalent of a list of `Object` in Java. So if you can amend your question to include more code, it will help identify where you're losing that type information.

Comment: I have tried some of the solutions from your answer before but I am getting  error ```No implicit arguments of type```

Comment: Hi datasure, there should be a type name after the word `type` in your error message, do you know it?

Comment: I am getting type as ```Any``` not enough arguments for method sorted: (implicit ord: scala.math.Ordering[Any])List[Any].
Unspecified value parameter ord.
  ```val abc = tr.map({ case (k, v) => (k, v.sorted)})```

Comment: Okay, so Scala's compiler lacks type information about what's in your list. Can you please edit your question to show us how you create the RDD, and what it's type signature is? I've edited my answer to show you my workings to help.

Comment: Updated the question as you suggested